# Warning message with new_ode_model in PKPDsim

Tags: r

I had to reinstall PKPDsim this morning due to some issues with R on my PC and since then I am getting this error below while I am trying to run the following.Seems like an older version does not give out this warning message (I ran it 1 AM this morning with no such message and my colleague with an older install still does not get this message while he is running the same code). Any help would be appreciated.

```
pk1 <- new_ode_model(code = "
                     dAdt[1] = -KA * A[1]
                     dAdt[2] =  Bio*KA * A[1]-(CL/V2)*A[2]-(Q/V2)*A[2]+(Q/V3)*A[3]
                     dAdt[3] =  (Q/V2)*A[2]-(Q/V3)*A[3]
                     ",obs=list(cmt=2,scale="V2"))

Warning messages:
1: In if (txt < 0) return(ode_def_orig) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

2: In if (txt < 0) return(ode_def_orig) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```